# Sliding Menu Under Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Currently I'm designing User Interface for my app. I want to implement sliding menu and action bar tabs features. I was able to do this, but I've encountered a slight problem - sliding menu should be above fragment, but in my case it's opposite.

Fragment

[image]

Opened Menu(Fragment overlays)

[image]

Here's code I used to make tabs:

```
List<Fragment> fragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (int i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
        Tab tab = bar.newTab();
        tab.setText("Tab " + i);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tab);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Fragment f = null;
    TabFragment tf = null;

    if (fragList.size() > tab.getPosition())
            fragList.get(tab.getPosition());

    if (f == null) {
        tf = new TabFragment();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putInt("idx",  tab.getPosition());
        tf.setArguments(data);
        fragList.add(tf);
    }
    else
        tf = (TabFragment) f;

    ft.replace(android.R.id.content, tf);

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (fragList.size() > tab.getPosition()) {
        ft.remove(fragList.get(tab.getPosition()));
    }

}
```

Slider Parameter Values:

```
    mSlidingPanel = (SlidingPaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.SlidingPanel);

    mSlidingPanel.setPanelSlideListener(panelListener);
    mSlidingPanel.setParallaxDistance(200);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MenuList);

    TitleText = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.title);

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(MixingSolutionsTransition.this , R.layout.custom_list , mList);
    mListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


   getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
   getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
   appImage = (ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.home);
```

TabFragment:

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

private int index;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle data = getArguments();
    index = data.getInt("idx");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
    tv.setText("Fragment " + (index + 1));

    return v;

    }



}
```

I can't find any similar questions on the net. What should I do?

Comment: how did you create tabs here ?

Comment: uploaded all the code regarding the tabs

Comment: Kindly put Activity layout as well

Comment: Added Slider Parameter Values code

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have created your tabs as `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`
 which means you want your Tabs to be part of action bar which will indicate on which tab you are on,

so the navigation drawer has adjusted itself to come below the tab, (As now tabs are part of action bar).

what you can do if lift your drawerlayout to the root of layout then your navigation drawer will appear over the action bar, In this case you will have both your tabs and Navigation drawer above action bar

Comment: removing that line makes tabs disappear

Comment: I not fully understand what you mean by that. So any explanatory documents(e.g. from android developer) would be nice. And won't this cause Sliding Menu overlay action bar(with menu, refresh buttons)?